# Set itextsharp textfield to be readonly

Tags: c#, itext, textfield

I've been trying to set a TextField to be readonly but with no success.

I've tried this:

```
 field.SetFieldProperty(key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, Nothing)
```

But it will give this error:
'iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField' does not contain a definition for 'SetFieldProperty'

Here's my code:

```
public void addField(PdfWriter writer, string name, int x, int y, int w, int h, PdfContentByte cb, int maxSize, string text, BaseFont font, int border)
    {
        TextField field = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(x, y - h, x + w, y), name);

        field.Text = text;

        writer.AddAnnotation(field.GetTextField());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [TextFields](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter08/TextFields.cs) example from [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book).

Different options can be set on a field. This is how you make a field read only:

```
text.Options = TextField.READ_ONLY;
```

The previous answer, given by Scorpi0 wasn't wrong (I upvoted the answer), but it's the solution to change the property of a field in an *existing* form. You're asking to change the property in a *newly created* form.

Answer (score 1):

The method `SetFieldProperty` is a method of the class `AcroFields` (PDF form), not a method of the class `TextField`.
A `TextField` is able to be readonly only if it belong to a Form, then you can set it readonly by calling the method `SetFieldProperty`, and by knowing the key of the `TextField` inside the Form.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
TextField newtext = new TextField(PDFStamper.Writer,
    new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(590, 660, 470, 690), "txtfield");
newtext.Options = TextField.READ_ONLY;
PdfFormField field = newtext.GetTextField();
PDFStamper.AddAnnotation(field, 1);
```